# How to use .htaccess to redirect to new website?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the website

http://oldname.edu/gailp2/CSSS508,

which I want to point to my new site,

https://newsite.com/site/gailp2csss508

I've tried a number of different ways to accomplish the redirect via .htaccess files.

First, I modified the .htaccess file in the folder CSSS508
as follows:

```
Redirect 301 / https://newsite.com/site/gailp2csss508
```

When I navigate to the old site (oldsite.edu/gailp2/CSSS508), I get the error
    "We're sorry, we were unable to locate the site /gailp2csss508gailp2/CSSS508"

It seems to be concatenating the file directories onto the name of the new website??

I've also tried a number of different variations, for example, trying to modify .htaccess files in different directories -- all unsuccessful.

Comment: What is CSSS508? Is this your css folder?

Comment: CSSS508 is the course name.  So the old course website is at oldname.edu/gailp2/CSSS508.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this `Redirect 301 /gailp2/CSSS508 https://newsite.com/site/gailp2csss508`

Comment: WOOHOOO !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!   You MADE MY DAY Dave, it worked.  And I worked on this for hours unsuccessfully.... thank you SO MUCH!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You could see it by the way it was getting concatenated. Happy Coding! :)